# MGFX in MonoGame on OS X

Tags: macos, shader, monogame

I'm having an immense amount of trouble trying to use shaders with MonoGame on OS X. From what I understand, it requires a command line tool called 2MGFX to compile a shader into a usable format; however, I am unable to locate a download for this tool. I poked around the MonoGame source code and found a SLN file for 2MGFX, but it does not compile. I feel like I'm missing something quite fundamental somewhere, but I absolutely cannot figure out what. Any help (or a build of 2GMFX that I can run) would be fantastic. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't compile MGFX on OSX. Find a Windows machine or, like i do, run a virtual machine on OSX. The MGFX project will compile on a Windows. Don't forget to install XNA Game Studio and Monogame on that Windows machine or else it will give errors.